# SPI read while writing?

Tags: spi

I'm working on a driver for an SPI device that returns some data (device status) while the command byte is still being written.  Is there a way to read this status data using standard Arduino APIs or do I need to bit-bang to access it?

Here's what the SPI signals look like:

[image: SPI timing diagram]

The 6 bits in red are the ones I'm interested in reading.

---

For context, the device in question is a Microchip [MCP3561 ADC](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP3561-2-4-Two-Four-Eight-Channel-153.6-ksps-Low-Noise-24-Bit-Delta-Sigma-ADCs-DS20006181B.pdf) (MCP3X6X series).  [It has a bug](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP3X5X-Family-Data-Sheet-Errata-DS80000845B.pdf) (erratum 2) where the new-data-ready flag (`/DR_STATUS`) is not always set correctly.  Part of the work-around involves reading the status bits mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The `SPI.transfer()` method](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPITransfer) is designed to send a byte through
the SPI port and, *at the same time* receive an incoming byte.

Usage pattern:

```cpp
uint8_t byte_to_send = ...;
uint8_t received_byte = SPI.transfer(byte_to_send);
```

Comment: Turns out the bug was elsewhere in my code.  This works fine.  Thanks!